# Why is TSQLT erroring out in SQLTest and not running when run manually?

Tags: redgate, tsqlt

I have a set of tests that run sometime when run through Redgate SQLTest and sometimes they give me the first error in the screenshot. When running my test code manually it takes about 22 seconds to execute.

Also when I run manually with the command below it says 0 tests executed and runs in < 1 second. I have no idea why my tests wont run.

```
EXEC tsqlt.Run @TestName = '[SolrShowConversion].Condition - No Condition     Record in Stage';
```

[image: errors]

Comment: what happens if you run this: `EXEC tsqlt.Run @TestName = '[SolrShowConversion].[Condition - No Condition     Record in Stage]';`?

Comment: Same thing. 0 tests executed.

Comment: Test procedure names  actually need to start with the word "test". SQLTest is hiding that fact from you. So there seems to be no procedure with the name you have been using in the database. Also check he spelling of the schema name.

Comment: Ahh..it automatically adds 'test' to the stored proc but you dont see that unless you look... Kicked it off and its running now. Thank you. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I can, but it seems that we haven't answered the bigger problem (the timeout) yet. How long does the test run standalone?

Comment: I made some progress... I had a tsqlt.setup file to run a sql job and wait for it to finish before it completes. The sql job takes about 45 min to complete, and I think it was timing out due to that. I disabled that and my tests are starting to pass... Not sure if i'm using the setup functionality the way it was intended or not.

Comment: 45 minutes is certainly more then you should have to wait for your tests to finish. Are you trying to preload data into the database? In my experience, the setup functionality almost never makes sense to use, as all test classes tend to contain at least one test that is "different".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection issue from the error. I also notice you're not running the latest version of SQL Test - go to Help->Check for updates and see if that helps.

We're about to ship a whole raft of improvements to SQL Test (probably next week) so keep an eye out for that.

Best way to raise issues with us is via support@red-gate.com

Hope that helps.

Comment: I upgraded and this did not fix the timeout issue.